# this.state is not a function

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, npm, jsx

need a helping hand, a stuck in a simple conditional rendering in reactJS
the code is:
I am changing the login and logout button based on the conditions. for eg. if the user is logged in, the button should be `Logout` and if the user is logged in then the button should be `Login`.

I am using react states for this functionality but somehow it's working for login but when I press logout it shows me an error: `this.state is not a function`

Hey if anyone can solve this please help me with this

> this is my main file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Rendering extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoggedIn: false };
    this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
    this.handleLogoutClick = this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this);
  }

  // handler function for logout
  handleLoginClick() {
    this.setState({
      isLoggedIn: true,
    });
  }

  // handler function for logout
  handleLogoutClick() {
    this.state({
      isLoggedIn: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;

    let button;
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
    } else {
      button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
    }
    return <div className="App">{button}</div>;
  }
}

// for login
function LoginButton(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.onClick}>Login</button>;
}
// for logout
function LogoutButton(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.onClick}>Logout</button>;
}
```

> this is the file where I am rendering the above file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// import the components
import Rendering from "./compnents/Rendering";

// render
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Rendering />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The error that I am getting is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wPlE.png

Comment: You should always read the error, it's a good habit to get in to. You are calling a non-existent function `this.state`, which the error tells you. You should also double check API documentation when you try to call an API method and get an unexpected response. You meant to call `this.setState`.

Comment: Right, you should use `this.setState({isLoggedIn : false})`